# Customize 'share' message in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I want my website to enable people to share their score via instant messengers.
So there is this nifty feature where you can share websites in Google Chrome on Android
with other people (on the screenshot it says 'Teilen'):

[image]

Right now all it does is for example messages people on whatsapp the title of the webpage and its URL, so I wondered if I could somehow customize this behavior.
So, is it possible?

Also, is there a way to trigger this share functionality via javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to influence this directly from a website, but there are two things you *can* do.

## Change url to highscore specific score

As soon as the user get's a new score use the history API `.replaceState` function to change the URL to a URL that for others will load a page with his highscore. And set `window.title` to what you want the title to be (though make sure this is something sensible for the player as well).

Triggering the share dialog from code is not possible.

## Cordova (+crosswalk)

If you really wish to trigger the share dialog from code you would have to bundle your application as a native application using Cordova (and crosswalk if it's a game). There are next [various plugins](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) that expose the share dialog from Javascript.